# Consumable In-App Purchase related to App Deletion

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've made an iOS app that starts the user with a certain number of an item. The user can buy more of these items via a consumable in-app purchase. The app is not a game so the state of the app does not matter (for example, the level they are on).

What can I do to prevent the user from simply uninstalling the application and receiving the starting number of items (rather than buying more)? I'm storing the items via NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your saved info to iOS KeyChain, they will probably be there for you.

See an example code at:
[KeychainItemWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html)